# Rails : why is there .keep file in every directory

Tags: git, version-control

I see `.keep` file in every directory in rails skeleton.
what is that file for?
What is its significance?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This is not for Rails actually, this is for git.

Git doesn't track "empty" directories, so, the directories like eg. "/logs" wouldn't end up in the repository. Having a `.keep` in it, marks the directory to be tracked.

#### Updates:

In Unix based systems, files starting with a dot(`.`) are considered hidden and do not appear in the UI. Hence they might not disturb you.